# Is it better to accept timedeltas or number of seconds?

Tags: python, timedelta

I'm contributing to an open source project, and in there, I'm querying for objects that were updated recently, so I have a function that accepts a max_age object. The person reviewing my code has a slight preference for passing around time in seconds. While it's not a big issue, I see this as a learning opportunity for me. Here's the conversation we had. For some context, we started out discussing the name of the argument.

code reviewer:

> max_age is fine I think, I had misread. I think max_age_timedelta is
>   also good (more explicit). Thinking about it more, is there a good
>   reason to not use seconds? As in, pass in an integer? Are there
>   significant speed issues?

me:

> no, just ease of use issues

code reviewer:

> I'm mildly in favor of passing objects between functions that are as simple as possible.

me:

> I'm querying based on dates, and timedeltas make date math easier.

code reviewer:

> Is it tricky to create a timedelta internally, with the number of seconds as input?
>   Or do you use the timedelta in so many places that it's going to be tedious to do that each time?
>   (nb: 'internally' meant 'internal to the function doing the querying')

me:

> It's not that hard, I could certainly just construct a timedelta internally.
>   But a timedelta object carries the semantics of being a length of time.
>   Integers and other basic data types get their semantics through argument and variable names.

code reviewer:

> Yep, I understand. However, in Python, stuff is untyped, so the main method of signaling we have is the variable name.
>   I.e. it's not easy to just tell what the type of an object is by looking at the code, as it is in C++.

What would you do in a case like this?

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to be entirely opinion based, there is no "right" answer. If you are contributing to someone else's project, you should conform to their standards even if you find it more cumbersome.

Comment: Don't consider your needs, that's selfish. Consider the needs of your callers. What is the form they're most likely to be using?

Answer (score 2):

1. Although the reviewer makes a valid point that in Python you can't tell by looking at the name of an object what type it is, I don't think this argument is applicable in this specific case - as this would be the case whether you pass a timedelta or int. Either way you won't be able to tell it's type. So I would ignore this argument.
2. If you already have a timedelta available, why convert it in various places. That's unnecessary overhead.
3. Consistency: if the rest of the code is passing ints and converting to timedeltas then I would stick with the current convention. If there is no such precedent in the code then I would pass timedeltas. Being consistent is important as other programmers who look at this codebase have certain expectations. Best not to annoy them!
4. Comment your code well. Use docstrings to list the type of the parameter.

In essence, if there are no precedents in the code of using an int, I see no problems with using timedelta.